# Should I keep content="index, follow" on pages where I have canonical to another site

Tags: search-engine-indexing, canonical-url, noindex

I have a URL on website A that contains content from website B. On-site A at the moment we include canonical that shows site B  and at the moment we do not include this URL into site A sitemaps.

Should the URL on-site A have content=" index,  follow" though we exclude it from the sitemaps because of canonical?

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is what we call a "cross-domain canonical". Google introduced it around ~2009-2010.

Typically, we use cross-domain canonicals to share content from another website that we really like and want to re-post it for our users. If it's another one of *your* sites, the way we deal with it doesn't change much.

### Cross-Domain Rel=Canonical

`rel=canonical` indicates the authoritative or "original" page. Think of it like "re-tweeting". Google will always rank the canonical URL in organic results.

When used cross-domain, it carries a lot of benefit for the site being on the receiving end of the canonical. In your example, the authority of *any/all* links that the page on site A might get will get passed to site B.

Within the SEO community, we think it's similar to a 301 redirect - something greater or equal to 90% of the link authority and ranking signals will transfer from site A to site B.

**The following would be best practice for your situation:**

*Revised instruction*

- On pages where you list a cross-domain canonical **don't list any meta robots tag.** Leaving it blank will default to the directive `all` which says `There are no restrictions for indexing or serving.`
- **Include** the URL in site A's sitemap. Treat the URL on site A exactly the same as you would with any other page. Site A will not
  get any rankings benefit from hosting this content. By the very
  nature of the rel=canonical tag, Site B get's the credit.
- On site A make sure your page has the same content (including images and media) and the same headline.
- Include the same links within the content on site A as are in the content on site B - This will ensure that Google counts your rel=canonical correctly.
- Link to the page on site B from the page site A. *This is optional, but a cool thing to do.*

Moreover, when you re-post content from someone else's website on yours, if you declare their page as the canonical you will **not** be punished for duplicate content.

**Additional Reasoning**

- `noindex follow` is fine as well if you do not want page indexed, but `follow` is necessary for search engines to crawl/verify the canonical. This is how they will corroborate that the content is the same.
- `noindex nofollow` doesn't help anyone. Here's why: under *some* circumstances *maybe* Google *will* want to show the result from site A. If both sites are in english, what if site A offers translation for non-english speaking users and Site B does not? What if site B's SSL cert expires? What if site B is super slow on mobile and site A is optimized?

So I digress if we are saying that site B is the canonical, site A will not get punished for duplicate content. Most likely Google will not index the page on site A *because it is not the canonical* `noindex nofollow` is redundant. The best route is to let Google decide.

Comment: "Site B will not get any rankings benefit from hosting this content. By the very nature of the rel=canonical tag, Site A get's the credit." - Haven't you got A and B the wrong way round here?

Comment: @MrWhite oof...yep...answer is updated

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use `content="index, follow"` on website A if you want it to not indexed by search engine.
Because Google will also index it and show it in search result pages.
But if you want the content of site A should be indexed by the search engine then you should use the index along with canonical.
Here is the screenshot from Google Search Central
[image]
Here is article from Google Search Central Blog
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content

Comment: Google does use the word "also" there, but I take it to mean that you can "instead" ask other sites to use `noindex`.   I don't think that it actually means that `index` with a canonical is problematic.   Your interpretation could be correct, but I'm not sure.   You get an upvote for finding this relevant documentation.

Comment: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />` - The `nofollow` would not seem necessary here, or even desirable in most cases. Like @Stephen, I would also question whether `noindex` is really necessary when you already have a cross-domain rel=canonical tag as stated in the question - although I can see it as a belt & braces approach, particularly if there could be some doubt as to whether B is really canonical.

Comment: Transparency is your best friend...this answer is wrong.

Comment: I think it's your choice to get indexed the content by search engine on site A.

Comment: @Khalil Sure that could be fine, but no-follow defeats the purpose of the canonical.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely Right @Mike Ciffone. Thanks for your clarification. Actually in this situation some other question arises. Like whether you want content of  Site A to be indexed by the search engine or not. If you want the content should be indexed by the search engine then don't use the no index and use canonical with index. If you want the content should not be indexed by the search engine then use no index and no follow, In this case the canonical should not be used.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the knowledge you share. You have clear the answer in simple words. We have a lot to learn from you.

Comment: @Khalil see my revised answer. After thinking about this for a bit I actually prefer to leave meta robots blank - the canonical URL is all that is needed.

Comment: @MikeCiffone Thanks for your precious time and the clarification.